# Remove duplicates in correlations in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, correlation

Please see the following issue:

```
P=rand(4,4);

for i=1:size(P,2)
for j=1:size(P,2)
    [r,p]=corr(P(:,i),P(:,j))
end
end
```

Clearly, the loop will cause the number of correlations to be doubled (i.e., corr(P(:,1),P(:,4)) and corr(P(:,4),P(:,1)). Does anyone have a suggestion on how to avoid this? Perhaps not using a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have four suggestions for you, depending on what exactly you are doing to compute your matrices.  I'm assuming the example you gave is a simplified version of what needs to be done.

## First Method - Adjusting the inner loop index

One thing you can do is change your `j` loop index so that it only goes from 1 up to `i`.  This way, you get a lower triangular matrix and just concentrate on the values within the lower triangular half of your matrix.  The upper half would essentially be all set to zero.  In other words:

```
for i = 1 : size(P,2)
    for j = 1 : i
     %// Your code here
    end
end
```

## Second Method - Leave it unchanged, but then use `unique`

You can go ahead and use the same matrix like you did before with the full two `for` loops, but you can then filter the duplicates by using `unique`.  In other words, you can do this:

```
[Y,indices] = unique(P);
```

`Y` will give you a list of unique values within the matrix `P` and `indices` will give you the locations of **where** these occurred within `P`.  Note that these are **column** major indices, and so if you wanted to find the row and column locations of where these locations occur, you can do:

```
[rows,cols] = ind2sub(size(P), indices);
```

## Third Method - Use `pdist` and `squareform`

Since you're looking for a solution that requires no loops, take a look at the `pdist` function.  Given a `M x N` matrix, `pdist` will find distances between each pair of rows in a matrix.  `squareform` will then transform these distances into a matrix like what you have seen above. In other words, do this:

```
dists = pdist(P.', 'correlation');
distMatrix = squareform(dists);
```

## Fourth Method - Use the `corr` method straight out of the box

You can just use `corr` in the following way:

```
[rho, pvals] = corr(P);
```

`corr` in this case will produce a `m x m` matrix that contains the correlation coefficient between each pair of columns an `n x m` matrix stored in `P`.

---

Hopefully one of these will work!

Comment: Thank you so much. The first method works best due to the nature of my code. The example was only a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

this works ?

```
for i=1:size(P,2)
for j=1:i
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just correlating each column with the other, then why not just use (straight from the documentation)

```
[Rho,Pval] = corr(P);
```

I don't have the Statistics Toolbox, but according to http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html,

*corr(X) returns a p-by-p matrix containing the pairwise linear correlation coefficient between each pair of columns in the n-by-p matrix X.*

Comment: That's very true. What I didn't mention in my question was that correlation was actually done later, the loop was also for something else as well. Thank you though.